# If $x_n\in S$ and $x_n\to x$ then $x\in S$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, random-variables

> Suppose $S$ is the *support* of a univariate cdf $F$. If $x_n\in S$ is a sequence of reals such that $x_n\to x$ then show that $x\in S$.

I believe the question is actually very very simple, in the sense that since, by definition, the support is a closed set, $x_n\in S$ and $x_n\to x$ implies $x\in S$.

Am I oversimplifying matters too much or am I actually correct?

Comment: Yes, that simple.

Comment: Why is $F$ even mentioned here at all?  The problem is just real analysis with no connection to probability.

Comment: If you look up "support", you will observe a tiny word describing it, "closed", which I believe, like me, many people do not know. I think the question basically checks if you know 1) the support is "closed", and 2) definition of closed set.